# Tab Bar customization

Tags: iphone, customization, uitabbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Twitter-esque UITabBarController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664208/twitter-esque-uitabbarcontroller)

How can we do tab like this ? [epicurious](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/epicurious-recipes-shopping/id312101965?mt=8)

How can we override the default tab bar style without losing app store approval?

Comment: I've asked a very similar question and got some good answers.  The process is the same. [Twitter-esque UITabBarController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664208/twitter-esque-uitabbarcontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be more better explained than this post already at SO:

[Custom colors in UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675433/custom-colors-in-uitabbar)